# How do I use a GraphQL query in Gatsby, that returns an array in Advanced Custom Fields (ACF)?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, graphql, gatsby

So I have a custom field type in Wordpress, that returns an array of song objects, however I'm not sure how to use them in my Gatsby/React code. I have attached the query and the format of the returned data as an image below.

How do I go about rendering through a loop that generates each item in the dictionary array. Or is there a better way to do this?

```
<div>            
    <h2>Release Date</h2>
    <p>{post.acf.release_date}</p>
    <h2>Composer</h2>
    <p>{post.acf.composer}</p>
    <h2>First Song Artist</h2>
    <p>{ artistName[0] }</p>
    <h2>First Song Title</h2>
    <p>{ trackName[0] }</p>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you use `JSON.parse()` on the `list_of_songs` field? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Thanks so much! That will work perfectly. I thought I may have to use Gatsby related logic, but forgot I could just use plain JS.